# Who won this Texas Hold’em hand?

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

[image: A hand of Tezax Hold 'Em]

Since both players have the same pair, should it go down to the suits, or are they supposed to split the pot?

Answer (score 1):

Split the pot. There is no real ranking of suits, so suit only matters for a flush.

Comment: It doesn't matter in a flush either: you can't have two flushes with different suits in a single hand of THE. ;)

Comment: @Galandil true. All I meant was that suit matters for flushes because that's what makes a flush a flush, being one suit.